# Rails - Remote Devise Login by posting credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am trying to create functionality that will allow a remote site to login a User by posting the login credentials through a form to the Devise Session Controller. Instead of having the user enter their credentials through the Devise Login page, they would instead be automatically logged-in.

I am not looking to remotely authenticate an API request and I am not looking to implement an SSO strategy. From the user's perspective, they would be using a different website and a new window would pop-up redirecting to my remote Rails application without having to login.

I have over-ridden the Devise Sessions controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
# Override the action you want here.

protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

def create
    puts "Made it in override"

    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

    puts "After the override method"
end
end
```

Here are the console results:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-24 22:59:54 -0500
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"user@abc.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Made it in override
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = 'greg@cronin.com'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `current_sign_in_at` = '2014-12-25 03:59:54', `last_sign_in_at` = '2014-12-25 03:54:32', `sign_in_count` = 38, `updated_at` = '2014-12-25     03:59:54' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
(78.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/reps/1
After the override method
Completed 302 Found in 261ms (ActiveRecord: 81.0ms)


Started GET "/reps/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-24 22:59:55 -0500
Processing by RepsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 9ms

Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-24 22:59:55 -0500
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 123ms (Views: 121.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The login logic executes and the login credentials are correct, but the redirect returns 401 Unauthorized and causes Devise to prompt for credentials again.

Any idea why the user has not been authenticated??

Comment: I would suggest a change from this approach to OmniAuth, OAuth, or any other kind of authentication transfer. What you're describing is hard to secure. The error message that you're seeing is because Devise is detecting that you're missing the Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) token that protects the users. Rails generates this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The cross-site request forgery (csrf) is doing what it's exactly designed to do, prevent users to send requests from outside the website into your pages, note this part in your log

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

In your controller you find:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

which means if there's a violation detected, don't use session data for the current request, so that's why you find that you're not logged in, I don't know how you can overcome it, but you can check [devise gem wikis](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) and read how to start a session from another server using the way you want ( other than removing the csrf protection )

You might also want to check [this blog post](http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/) which was linked to [from here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Remote-authentication-with-Devise)